# Sort foreign keys by how many times they match with specified foreign key

Tags: sql

I have a table with composite keys `id` and `name`, where id is foreign key to another table.

```
id name
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 b
2 f
3 b
3 c
3 f
4 f
```

And i need to sort which id-s have most matching 'name' values as id for example 1.
Here, result would be [3, 2] (id 4 doesn't match one time), id3 matches 2 times (b and c) and id2 matches 1 time (b).

How would I query this?

Ideally it would return ordered pairs of (id, match_count).

Comment: Still not clear to me. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: There is a table with foreign key `id` and column `name`. I need a query that searches which `id` has most `name` matches with id=1. Id=1 has names `a`, `b`, `c`, so id-s with most matches are as follows: id=3 (matches on 'b' and 'c') and id=2 (matches on `b`). id=4 doesn't have any `name` matching with id=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be done with a join and group by:

```
-- using id = 1 as reference

select t1.id, count(*) as match_count
from (select id, name from t where id <> 1) as t1
join (select name from t where id = 1) as t2 on t1.name = t2.name
group by t1.id
order by match_count desc
```